# how to get exif using Camera2 API when i set the format to YUV

Tags: android, android-camera2

my camera app using ImageFormat.YUV_420_888 to capture images and do some process after, but when I save the file I also want to save the EXIF info in it, but the info I get from CaptureResult is limited. so I'm wondering there is any way I can get the complete EXIF info just like a when I use JPEG format?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

The CaptureResults from the camera2 API generally include the same information as in the camera EXIF, on devices with the LIMITED or higher level support.

Comment: thank you for your answer! but I can't find these value in my result, like 1.FocalLengthIn35mmFilm
2. ExposureMode
3. MeteringMode.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar issue. In order to get FocalLengthIn35mmFilm, I head to make a dummy JPEG capture, retrieve this value from ExifInterface, save it, and go on to work with YUV_420_888.